# Phonegap Create

Tags: bash, cordova, terminal, phonegap-cli

when I cd into the proj dir in the Terminal and then I type:

"phonegap create"

It just gives me:

```
Description:

  Creates a new application at the provided path.

  The application name and package ID can also be customized.
  These values are set in the app manifest (config.xml) and are used when
  creating a native project (platforms/<platform>/).

  The application can be created from an existing template as well. You can
  use any template that is published on npm, in your local file path, or available
  from a git URL. PhoneGap also recommends a few popular templates and provides
  shortened names for each. You can list the recommended templates with the
  `template list` command.

  The [config] option allows you to pass a JSON string, which will be injected
  into `<path>/.cordova/config.json`.

Options:

  --name, -n <name>                        application name (default: "Hello World")
  --id, -i <package>                       package name (default: "com.phonegap.hello-world")
  --copy-from, -src <path>                 create project using a copy of an existing project
  --link-to <path>                         symlink/shortcut to the www assets without copying
  --template <npm package|path|git url>    create app using template found on npm,
                                           your local path, or a git URL.

Examples:

  $ phonegap create path/to/my-app
  $ phonegap create path/to/my-app "com.example.app" "My App" 
  $ phonegap create path/to/my-app --id "com.example.app" --name "My App" 
  $ phonegap create path/to/my-app --copy-from ../my-other-app
  $ phonegap create path/to/my-app --template hello-world
  $ phonegap create path/to/my-app --template phonegap-template-hello-world

Also See:

  $ phonegap help template
  $ phonegap help template list
```

Instead of actually creating the project? This worked fine before but now it just gives me a description?!

Comment: You have tagged this as PhoneGap Build. This is not a question about PGB. Please update your tags.

Comment: Can you please answer the question though?

Comment: I'm a PhoneGap Build user so cannot answer your PhoneGap CLI questions I'm afraid. Change your tags and someone who knows about PhoneGap CLI may see it and help you.

Comment: The documentation suggests using `phonegap create path/to/my-app`. Have you tried passing a path as 2nd argument ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the terminal window might have cut off the first line of the `phonegap create` output, which is the usage line:

```
Usage: phonegap create [options] <path> [id [name [config]]]
```

From this, it looks like the `<path>` is required. Which is why you were seeing the description help text instead of a project getting created.

I honestly don't remember if the CLI for the phonegap command has changed recently or not. It's just not one of those commands that's used all that often (`build` and `run`, on the other hand...). I just get the syntax correct enough to start the project and start customizing the sample code from there. :-)